Working with continuous (wrapped) images - viewing pipe internal wall
I am working with image (using Python and OpenCV) which is a projection view of pipe internals. Imagine you put camera inside the pipe and it turns 360* taking a panorama photo. The outcome picture would have it's left and right side, but in reality, those edges touch each other.
What is the effective way to work with such data in Python? I am running some shape recognition on the image, but I need my program to understand, that the shape may be divided by the "cut" in the middle.
Below are the two cases. First one  shows processing of a picture without wrapping. Blue circles are the blobs detected by cv2.SimpleBlobDetector, but it cannot find the blop on the bottom right.

My best guess so far is to copy part of the left side of the image and append it to the right side. Below is the image above, but I copied 10% of the left side of the picture and append it to the right side. Then cv2.SimpleBlobDetector (with same parameters as above) detects bottom right blob without problem.

I have a gut feeling there must be a better way to work with such data. I just cannot find it.

Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

i.e. pics please. you could derive a projection that has its discontinuities where you don't mind them. browse some map projections applied to earth.

Thank you, I have added some pictures to better visualize my problem. I am not posting any code, because my question is not from the domain of "why is this code not working as expected". It's more conceptual, like "which modules can I possibly use for this task". So I don't think any of my already-written code is useful here.

the blob detector might just not like blobs sticking to the edges. pad with 1 px? also, usually white is considered object, black is background. -- extending the image with 10% or whatever of left side copy is a fair approach. no generic building blocks are made to handle cylinder/torus surfaces. as suggested, you could change the projection, so it'd look like a polar plot, but that brings its own issues (no longer "isotropic" or whatever term applies), so I wouldn't recommend going that route.

DIPlib does have a “periodic” boundary condition. Most functions in DIPlib allow to select a different boundary condition for each dimension. In your case you’d use “periodic” for the first (horizontal) axis and probably stick with the default “mirror” for the second. One of the original authors of DIPlib worked with borehole imaging and this is what he did.

I've got to remember to give diplib a look when I've got some occasion.
